# how to merge different files that have the same header but slightly different file name?

Tags: files, merge

I have a problem in merging files for a big data sets like below.
I want you help me to let me know the script that can do such task.

fine name: fluxes_year_lat_long
I have 30 years of daily fluxes files for more that 100 location(lat_long)
I want to merge from year 1 to year 30 of each point files.

my file looks like this

file name1: `fluxes_2000_50_70`

```
2000 1 1 5000 ....
2000 1 2 2000 ....
.
.
.
2000 12 31 5000
YYYY M D Fluxes
```

file name2: `fluxes_2001_50_70`

```
2001 1 1 5000
YYYY M D Fluxes
.
.
.
```

all the way to:

file name30: `fluxes_2030_50_70`

```
2030 1 1 5000
YYYY M D Fluxes
.
.
.
```

The number of rows for each file is the same.

I want the output to be merging the daily fluxes from year 2000 to 2030 for each point's
location like

output file: `fluxes_lat_long`

```
YYYY MM DD Fluxes value.
```

In addition, I want the script read and merge file starting with  the name fluxes_.
I appreciate your response.

Comment: do you want to concatenate the files? are they already sorted? Seems you need cat, cut and some awk, do you want to add them in order just removing the first YYYY D M FLuxes line?

Comment: `paste` might also be appropriate

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you are asking that given files:

```
fluxes_2000_10_10   fluxes_2001_10_10    fluxes_2003_10_10
```

and

```
fluxes_2000_20_10   fluxes_2001_20_10    fluxes_2003_20_10
```

You create a "total" file for each of the above files at latitude 10_10 and then 20_10 etc.

In which case:

```
bash$ for lat in $(ls -1 fluxes_* | sed 's/fluxes_[0-9]*_\([0-9]*_[0-9]*\)/\1/' |sort|uniq )
do 
    echo "processing $lat ..." 
    cat fluxes_[0-9]*_${lat} > fluxes_TOT_${lat} 
done
```

`ls -1 fluxes_* | sed 's/fluxes_[0-9]*_\([0-9]*_[0-9]*\)/\1/' | sort | uniq`  finds all the unique latitudes (x_y) number pairs, we then step through them with a `for` loop and `cat` the contents of the files at that latitude (all the years) and outputs them to `fluxes_TOT_x_y`.

Comment: your script is almost working my work, but it reads all the files and folders in the folder I am working on. Can you please let the script do read and merge only fluxes_YYYY_lat_long? Thank you for helping

Comment: Ah yes it will, change it to: `$(ls -1 fluxes_* | sed 's/fluxes_[0-9]*_\([0-9]*_[0-9]*\)/\1/' |sort|uniq )` - I will edit the answer accordingly

Comment: Great, but I think I may have caused confusion, you have the ability on the site to accept the answer (clicking the tick by my answer), details are on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Dear  Drav Sloan, I encountered a problem when I am running the code. It was working earlier,now it isn't. It should process the lat not the whole file name to cat for the specific lat_long. Here is the log file. processing fluxes_2007_-65_-147...
cat: fluxes_[0-9]*_fluxes_2007_-65_-147: No such file or directory
processing fluxes_2008_-65_-147...
cat: fluxes_[0-9]*_fluxes_2008_-65_-147: No such file or directory. there is no output result. Looking for your response. Thank you

Comment: Dear Drav Sloan, I just want to let you know the script I am using.                                   #!/bin/bash
for lat_long in $(ls -1 fluxes_*|sed 's/fluxes_[0-9]*_\([0-9]*_[0-9]*\)/\1/'|sort|uniq)
do
    echo "processing $lat_long..."
    cat fluxes_[0-9]*_${lat_long} > fluxes_${lat_long}
done

Answer (score 2):

I would use `sort -u fluxes_*`_lat_long > fluxes_lat_long`, it is by far the simplest solution.

**EDIT: use in a script**

```
for file in $(ls -1 fluxes_20*_*_*) ; do
    export ll="$(echo $file |cut -d _ -f 3,4)"  # extract lat & long
    echo "sort -u fluxes_*_$ll"  "> fluxes_$ll" # create sort instruction
done | uniq | sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirements, you want to merge all the flux data for one point in `fluxes_lat_long` with the format

```
01 01 Fluxes total_fluxes_for_Jan_1_over_30_years
01 02 Fluxes total_fluxes_for_Jan_2_over_30_years
...
```

If that's the case, here's a Perl script that should help:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = glob 'fluxes_*_*_*';
my %points;
$files[$_] =~ /_([0-9]+_[0-9]+)\Z/ and $points{$1}++ for (0..$#files);

for my $point (sort keys %points){
    my @point_files = grep { /_$point\Z/ } @files;
    my %days;
    for my $file (@point_files){
        open my $f,'<',$file or die "Failed to open file $file : $!\n";
        <$f>; #Discard the header
        while(<$f>){
            my ($year,$month,$day,$number) = split;
            $days{"$month $day"}+=$number;
         }
         close $f;
     }

     open my $of,'>',"fluxes_$point";
     for (sort by_date keys %days){
         print $of "$_ Fluxes $days{$_}\n";
     }
 }

 sub by_date{
    my ($month_a,$day_a) = split /\s*/,$a;
    my ($month_b,$day_b) = split /\s*/,$b;
    my $month_sort = $month_a <=> $month_b;
    my $day_sort = $day_a <=> $day_b;
    return $month_sort ? $month_sort : $day_sort
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. you understand my question. Actually Daniel's script did what I wanted. when I tried your scrip, I have the following error massage.

Comment: "my" variable $month_a masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./abraham.pl line 32.
"my" variable $month_b masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./abraham.pl line 32.
"my" variable $day_a masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./abraham.pl line 33.
"my" variable $day_b masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./abraham.pl line 33.
"my" variable $month_sort masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./abraham.pl line 34.
"my" variable $month_sort masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./abraham.pl line 35.
syntax error at ./abraham.pl line 24, near "&by_date keys"

Comment: Invalid separator character '$' in attribute list at ./abraham.pl line 35, near "$month_sort : return "
Execution of ./abraham.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Abraham All fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems all error is fixed. But I couldn't get output when running the script. The log file is empty. Thank you

Comment: @Abraham That's really strange because I tested it on my box and it works. It seems that your files are formatted in a different way to what the script is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate, you can do it easily:

```
cat fluxes_2001_50_70 >> fluxes_2000_50_70
```

But you do it when your files don't increase their volumne.

However , your question is behind of set of other question such as:

"second file should be update after merging?"

Answer (score 0):

`tail -qn +2` will remove the headers and start from the second line for every file, `fluxes_*` will glob all the files that starts with that string, and `> fluxes_2000_2030` will pipe all data to a single output file:

```
tail -qn +2 fluxes_* > fluxes_2000_2030
```